# Mouse and keyboard don't work on an Inspiron 2650 after installation

Tags: 10.10, keyboard, touchpad, installation

I just downloaded Ubuntu 10.10 to an older laptop (Inspiron 2650-Pentium 4) using the Windows installer (Windows XP is the other OS).  Everything seemed to be working fine but when the computer updated and asked me to restart, neither the keyboard or the mouse would work.  There seem to be a lot of people who have experienced this problem.

Which fix is the easiest to do since I'm not very computer savy.  And also, I don't know what it means when the instructions for a fix, say to open a terminal, and run some code. Is there some documentation or a website where I could find out how to do this to run the fix.

Please Help--This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Well, if neither the keyboard nor the mouse work, you're not going to be able to open a terminal the normal way.  Try starting the machine using the "recovery" option in the boot menu.

Comment: To open a terminal press Ctrl+Alt+T :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the Grub Menu? Grub is the menu you see to choose which operating system you need to run.

When the machine is starting holding down the shift key will bring up the Grub menu, there you can choose a recovery, or choose a previous version of the linux kernel. My current kernel is 2.6.35-28, and if this version prevented me from booting up I would have to choose a kernel with a lower number 2.6.35-22 as an example. Notice the lower number after the - minus sign?

It is most likely a video card issue. Another advice is to make sure not to have any memory cards, usb keys, usb hardrives attached, as it may be stuck thinking that it may be a boot up device.